# python - how to get the data from an plt.imshow()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code

```
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = plt.imshow(scipy.misc.lena())
```

and what I'm hoping to achieve is get the data on lena by accessing `a` or it's children.

The reason is I'll be accessing the image as `plt.gcf()` or `plt.gca()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`a` should be a `matplotlib.image.AxesImage` instance, in which case you can use

```
a.get_array()
```

and

```
a.set_array(data)
```

The array is stored as a `masked array`.

**Example**

There's an official example available at http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html.

**Direct access**

You can also use

```
a._A
```

to access the array data directly, though I imagine that the getters and setters are the preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

```
### get image from the plot ###
plt.figure()

...

plt.imshow(image)

# remove white padding
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)
plt.axis('off')
plt.axis('image')

# redraw the canvas
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.canvas.draw()

# convert canvas to image using numpy
img = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
img = img.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))

# opencv format
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

plt.close()
```