# Generate opencv-image without ticks and white border

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to generate images with `opencv` without it adding a white border and tick marks around the image.

**Here is an example image.**

[image]

**This is an example of what I want it to return.**

[image]

Comment: So given the example image, are you trying to return its untouched copy?  Removing the border is trivial, but if you want the actual original pixels, that's a difficult problem.  A suggestion I have is to do image inpainting but you need to detect those coloured boxes and supply that as a mask into the process - this is also not guaranteed to give you the original image.  Also, please show what you've tried to solve this problem. This page is useful: [ask].

Comment: No sorry. I am trying to return the identical first image without the white boarder

Comment: How are you actually producing the first image?  It looks like you're using `matplotlib` to display the image.  If that's the case, link #1 to remove all of the borders and axes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces.  Link #2 to actually obtain the image data from the window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345165/python-how-to-get-the-data-from-an-plt-imshow.